# Create a subset of a Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

If I have a data frame of email address like this from Hive:

```
email_address    user_id

test@test.com    2134
null             2133
test4@test.com   2132
test5@test.com   21
test6@test.com   213
test7@test.com   21388
null             22
null             2134
```

I want to create two dataframes (one dataframes which have all the user_id's with emails that are null and the other dataframe which has all the user_id's with emails that are not null) Something like this:

```
First Dataframe:               Second Dataframe:

test@test.com    2134          null             22
test4@test.com   2132          null             2134
test5@test.com   21            null             2133
test6@test.com   213
test7@test.com   21388
```

I have this code below:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("YOUR_APP_NAME").setMaster("local[10]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)

hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.uris", "METASTORE_URI_NAME_HERE")

val df = hiveContext.sql("SELECT email,user_id FROM USERS")

df.map{ row =>
    if row.getString(0).length > 0 {
        //ADD INTO "First Dataframe"
        //row.getString(0) = email, row.getString(1) = user_id
    }else {
        //ADD INTO "First Dataframe"
        //row.getString(0) = email, row.getString(1) = user_id
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I need to create a whole new Dataframe or how I would do it in the first place either. Any pointers?

Comment: Is one option to convert the `df` variable into an rdd then filter out all of the email address which are not null and convert that rdd into a dataframe. And then filter out all of the email address that are null (from the original rdd) and convert that rdd into a dataframe? So I will have two dataframes then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the dataframe function `isNull()` is easier in this case.

```
df_no_nulls = df.where(col("email_address").isNull())

df_nulls = df.where(col("email_address").isNotNull())
```